# Can I use Appium desktop to run test scripts?

Tags: testing, appium, e2e-testing

Have gone through several Appium Desktop tutorial but all of them only showed how to **manually** test in the inspector window.

Does Appium desktop support automation test scripts? If so, how to send my tests written in node to it, or is there a handy npm package for the connection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally connected `webdriver` to `appium`. Turns out webdriver can also be used for mobile testing.

Here are several points got me confused, hope it can help those who came into the same scene:

1. `webdriver` is not web exclusive - it can also be used for mobile e2e testing.
2. Appium server and Appium inspector do not necessarily work together. Once the server is started, it can be connected by an appium inspector or other services, e.g. webdriver.
3. Inspector is mostly for manual inspection. So far I haven't seen the possibility to supply automation test scripts to it.

And here's a complete [walkthrough](https://nishantverma.gitbooks.io/appium-for-android/content/) to those who're not familiar with Appium.